# Simple messaging queue for inter-app communication over internet

Tags: software-recommendation, application-development

I'm looking to organize simple messaging queue for inter-app communications.
The applications will be running on different PC's connected thought Ubuntu One service.

Basically I thought to use desktopcouch, but I just found that Canonical dropped couchdb support from U1 and I'm afraid it won't sync anymore.

I also found [U1DB](http://people.canonical.com/~aquarius/u1db-docs/) which is counterpart of desktopcouch features, but it is not yet available in 12.04 archives.

Am I missing anything? :)

Answer (score 0):

Support for desktopcouch was dropped, but couchdb itself still has built-in support for syncing over the internet and is heavily used by Novacut for exactly that purpose.

Comment: I'm a bit aware of couchdb features, but wondering if that still use U1 for syncing or it should relies on some other cloud services?